# Using systemservice in service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-context

I'm starting a service:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service_Location_Manager.class);
                    startService(intent);
```

And then that service gives a null pointer:

```
 public Service_Location_Manager() {
    super("Service_Location_Manager");

    wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  }
```

How do I use the SystemService? I tried this, this.getApplicationContext, this.getBaseContext, but it all gives a null pointer:

```
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:393)
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621):     at com.testapp.Service_Location_Manager.<init>(Service_Location_Manager.java:57)
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-20 14:48:05.305: E/AndroidRuntime(6621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2246)
```

Comment: You'll probably want to move those `getSystemService()` calls into the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out, stupid.. thanks!

Comment: As @MH. says. In short, never do anything in a constructor for the main Android components such as Service or Activity classes. The onCreate method is called automatically by the OS once they've been propeley initialised and until tonCreate is called, you shouldn't be doing anything.